# Excel workbook created using VBA does not contain macros

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I recently created a VBA macro in Excel to email spreadsheets. The spread sheets that I want to email are created using another VBA program. The program takes a part number as input and then opens Excel and grabs the corresponding data from a SQL Server database.

My issue is that Excel pops up during the retrieval of the information does not contain the macro I created. If I copy the data and open a new blank Excel workbook, my macro is there. If I save the spreadsheet and then reopen it my macro also appears.

Is the way that VBA creates a new Excel workbook somehow causing my macros not to appear? Is there any way to fix this? In the end I would like to email the spreadsheet the minute the VBA program has finished creating it.

Here is a code snippet as to how I am creating the Excel workbook.

```
xlApp = New Excel.Application ' Create new Workbook
xlApp.Visible = True
xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Array.Sort(snarry)
On Error Resume Next

For i = 0 To inxms - 1 ' Select Column Widths
    xlWorksheet.Range(xlWorksheet.Cells(1, i + 2), xlWorksheet.Cells(2, i + 2)).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 10
Next i

' Display Measurement Types
offst = 7
xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, 1) = "S/N"
For i = 0 To inxms - 1
    xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, i + 2) = measures(i)
Next
xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, inxms + 2) = "Ref#"

frst = True
For ims = 0 To inxms - 1
    frstmeas(ims) = True
Next ims
strSheetRev = ""
strSheetRef = ""
strskiprev = ""
strskipref = ""
offst = offst + 1
For i = 0 To inx - 1
    snskiprev = False
    snskipref = False
    For ims = 0 To inxms - 1
        Call FillMeasurements(Conn, xlWorksheet, pn, snarry(i), measures(ims), meastyp(ims), 1 + offst, ims + 2, inxms + 2, frst, frstmeas(ims), tester(ims), testdate(ims), numdg(ims), strRef, ckbNotes.Checked)
    Next
    xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, 1) = snarry(i)
    offst = offst + 1
Next

' Add Tolerances
offst = offst + 1
xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, 1) = "Max"
xlWorksheet.Cells(2 + offst, 1) = "Nom"
xlWorksheet.Cells(3 + offst, 1) = "Min"
For ims = 0 To inxms - 1
    Call FillTolerances(Conn, xlWorksheet, pn, measures(ims), meastyp(ims), 1 + offst, ims + 2, numdg(ims))
Next ims
offst = offst + 3

' Add Tester
offst = offst + 1
xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, 1) = "Tested By"
xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst + 1, 1) = "Test Date"
For i = 0 To inxms - 1
    If (Not frstmeas(i)) Then
        xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst, i + 2) = tester(i)
        xlWorksheet.Cells(1 + offst + 1, i + 2) = Format(testdate(i), "MM/dd/yyyy")
    End If
Next

Conn.Close()

' Display Header
midloc = CInt((inxms + 1) / 2#)
If (midloc < 4) Then
    midloc = 4
End If
xlWorksheet.Cells(1, midloc) = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
xlWorksheet.Cells(2, midloc) = txtTitle.Text
xlWorksheet.Cells(3, 1) = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
xlWorksheet.Cells(4, 1) = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
xlWorksheet.Cells(5, 1) = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
xlWorksheet.Cells(3, inxms) = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
xlWorksheet.Cells(3, inxms + 1) = pn & "-" & strSheetRev
xlWorksheet.Cells(3, inxms + 2) = vendor

' Display messages for skipped sns
strSkip = ""
If (strskiprev <> "") Then
    strSkip = strSkip & "S/Ns skipped for Rev mismatch" & Chr(10) & Mid$(strskiprev, 2) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
End If
If (strskipref <> "") Then
    strSkip = strSkip & "S/Ns skipped for Ref mismatch" & Chr(10) & Mid$(strskipref, 2)
End If
If (strSkip <> "") Then
    MsgBox (strSkip)
End If

txtPN.Text = ""
txtTitle.Text = ""
ckbNotes.Checked = False
GoTo Dne

BadSN:
    MsgBox ("Bad SN specification")
    GoTo Dne
Dne:
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, not sure why it's reasonable to expect that a "new blank excel workbook" should contain macros. Are you sure you're not tricking yourself here either via use of the XLSTART folder or your own default template? And code, show some code, such as how you're creating the new workbook.

Comment: Ill add the code for how I'm creating the excel workbook. I was expecting the new excel workbook to contain the macros because I created an excel add in so I assumed no matter what sheet I opened or what new blank workbook was made my macros would show regardless. Is that not the case?

Comment: @RizwanChaudry - Please see how to create a [mcve]. I removed some commented-out code but it still needs cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

An "Add-in" is something that is installed on and located to a particular computer. It does not get embedded within a workbook. Instead there is an application-wide setting which indicates whether an add-in is "installed" or not. In VBA, property Application.AddIns(index).Installed can be used to enable or disable an add-in (identified via index, which can be the name of the add-in). Unfortunately, "Installed" is a misnomer; really it means enabled/disabled, and installation is another matter entirely. If your add-in is essential, it will need to be installed on each computer that requires it.

Comment: Hi rskar, I apologize for the late response your suggestion worked as far as now the add-in appears in the add-in list, but the add-in does not execute. Any suggestions as to how I can remedy this? My add-in creates a new menu in excel when excel is opened. I guess since VBA isn't really starting up excel and is only creating a new workbook could this be the issue? Thank your for all of your help and time.